# R- ggplot bubblechart sized by average value of group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a bubblechart where I have multiple z values for each xy coordinate. I want the size of the `geom_point` to be the average z value for each xy coordinate / interaction- my expected output would be something like:

[image]

I tried grouping by the interaction of x and y values, but can't get `ggplot` to take the mean for the group. Instead, I'm getting either the mean of the entire dataset or plotting multiple points at the same xy location, each with its own size set by the z value. Here is how I tried the former:

```
library(ggplot2)

z <- seq(1,20, length.out = 18)
xy <- expand.grid(c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3))
xyz <- data.frame(xy, z)
names(xyz) <- c("x", "y", "z")

ggplot(xyz, aes(x, y, group = interaction(x,y)))+
  geom_point(size = z, position = position_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0))
```

Which gives this plot (with jitter to show multiple points being plotted):

[image]

So- is it possible to group by xy locations and set size by the mean value of each location? Of course, I can find the mean first if necessary, but I'm wondering if there is a way in ggplot itself.

Thanks in advance, please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: I thin your closest built-in ggplot bet would be `stat_bin_2d`, which does group 2d points, but it doesn't support the geom and aesthetics you want. Just do your data transformation up front and pass the aggregate data to ggplot.

Comment: @Gregor Fair enough, if it can't be done that way that's the way it goes. And you're right, `stat_bin_2d` doesn't quite get me where I need. Thanks!

Comment: `ggplot` is a plotting package. For convenience, it has the ability to do some basic aggregations, but there's no real benefit in getting a plotting package to do your data manipulations for you when it's an easy line or two in `data.table` or `dplyr`.

Comment: @Gregor That makes complete sense. I ran into a case where I could have saved a few lines by doing the manipulation with ggplot and got curious as to whether it was possible (and now have spent much more time trying to figure out if it was possible than if I had gone about this as normal). Thanks for the info and clarification!

Comment: Yeah, and it's a fine question to ask if there is a way to do stuff like this in ggplot, just don't be surprised if the answer is "no".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Gregor for pointing me to `stat_bin_2d` which got me to the solution that ended up working for me:

```
library(ggplot2)

z <- runif(81, min = 4, max = 10)
xy <- expand.grid(c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3))
xyz <- data.frame(xy, z)
names(xyz) <- c("x", "y", "z")

ggplot(xyz, aes(x, y, z = z), col = "black")+
  stat_summary_2d(aes(size = ..value..), geom = "point")+
  scale_size(range = c(4, 15))+
  guides(fill = FALSE)
```

Which outputs something like:

[image]

Although this technically does what I want, as Gregor and Nicolas pointed out- this is rarely going to be the correct way to go about doing this.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you there. Albeit I would rather pivot/summarise the data first, and then ggplot the summarised df.

```
 ggplot(data = (xyz %>% group_by(x, y) %>% summarise(z.mean = mean(z))),
         aes(x, y, size = z.mean)) + 
 geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0))
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for a solution that definitely does work, but specifically I'm wondering about doing this with ggplot grouping mechanics rather than looking for a way to aggregate/summarize. Thanks for the answer!